# Vba double click on cell to highlight then double click another cell removes first cells highlight

Tags: vba, excel

I have found on a previous question asked how to copy a cell (say A1) into another cell (say B1) when double clicked from a range of cells (say A1 to A4). I have also found how to highlight the double clicked cell (A1). When I double click on A2, it's value then replaces the value already in B1. Now both A1 and A2 are highlighted instead of just A2 being highlighted. I want the second double click to remove the highlighting from the first double click.
The vb i'm using is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(target, Range("A1:A4")) Is Nothing Then
Cancel = True
target.Copy
Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

With target.Interior
    If Not .ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("A1:A4")) Is Nothing Then
        .ColorIndex = 15
    ElseIf Not .ColorIndex = 15 Then
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End With
Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want only one cell to be highlighted and have no other formatting in your cells, you can just clear all the formatting at the start of every double click:

```
target.Parent.UsedRange.ClearFormats
```

Alternatively, you could store the previous cell location in a public variable and then remove the formatting on a new click:

```
Public PreviousCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not PreviousCell Is Nothing Then PreviousCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

.... your code here ....

Set PreviousCell = target

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @RGA the second solution is perfect! How would I set the range for only A1:A4 as i've got another set of data in A5:A10 and at the moment if I double click a cell in the second range, the highlighted cell in A1:A4 is removed. I want to end up with 2 highlighted cells, 1 from each range.

Comment: @cah1991 then what you should do is create two "PreviousCell" variables (`PreviousCell1` and `PreviousCell2` for example), then check which range has been double clicked by checking the row and column of `target`.  Use PreviousCell1 to refer to A1:A4 and PreviousCell2 to refer to A5:A10, and only reset the one for the corresponding region (using If statements accordingly)

Comment: Thanks @RGA  I've added this is to end but now the first range isn't highlighting, only the second range is. What am I missing from this?

Public PreviousCell2 As Range
If Not PreviousCell2 Is Nothing Then PreviousCell2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
With target.Interior
If Not .ColorIndex = xlNone Then
.ColorIndex = xlNone
ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("A5:A10")) Is Nothing Then
.ColorIndex = 15
ElseIf Not .ColorIndex = 15 Then
.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If
End With
Cancel = True Set PreviousCell2 = target
End Sub

Comment: @cah1991 could you open a new question with that issue and code, and comment here with a link to the new question? Very hard to read code in a comment, and it is technically a new question

Comment: Thanks @RGA this is the link to the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38500441/vba-highlight-double-clicked-cell-with-second-double-click-removing-formatting-f