# Vba highlight double clicked cell with second double click removing formatting from 2 ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have two ranges A1:A4 and A5:A10. I want to be able to highlight a cell when it is double clicked from the first range say A1, when I then double click on a cell in the same range say A2 this will then unhighlight A1 and highlight A2. I want to do the same for the second range but independently of each other so I will end up with 2 highlighted cells, one from each range. The code i am currently using only does this for the second range at the moment:

```
Public PreviousCell As Range
Public PreviousCell2 As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not PreviousCell Is Nothing Then PreviousCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone



With target.Interior
    If Not .ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("A1:A4")) Is Nothing Then
        .ColorIndex = 15
    ElseIf Not .ColorIndex = 15 Then
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End With
Cancel = True

Set PreviousCell = target

If Not PreviousCell2 Is Nothing Then PreviousCell2.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

With target.Interior
    If Not .ColorIndex = xlNone Then
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    ElseIf Not Intersect(target, Range("A5:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        .ColorIndex = 15
    ElseIf Not .ColorIndex = 15 Then
        .ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
End With
Cancel = True

Set PreviousCell2 = target

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cell is double-clicked in `Range("A1:A4")` then clear the color from the whole range and the highlight the Target range.  DO the same for `Range("A5:A10")`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A4")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1:A4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A10")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A5:A10").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that solution is perfect!

Comment: Thank you for the check!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ok I see the issue now.  The problem is that you are setting BOTH previous cell values to `target`, regardless of the range selected.  You need to change the `PreviousCell` and `PreviousCell2` to target *only when **their*** corresponding range is changed.  So if `Target` is within A1:A4, then `PreviousCell` will be changed, and if `Target` is within A5:A10, then `PreviousCell2` should be changed accordingly.